# Change celery setting task_always_eager for a single unit test case

Tags: python, flask, celery, pytest

I have a specific test case in which I utilize the celery backend so I need the task_always_eager setting to be false or I will get a RuntimeError. The problem is however I need all other test cases ran with the setting true, so I am trying to set the celery config task_always_eager to false just for this test case using a celery mark annotation. However, It doesn't look like it is doing anything.

Here is a skeleton of my task:

```
@pytest.mark.celery(task_always_eager=False)
def test_task(self):
   # do some stuff to start a task
   do_stuff()
   # do some stuff to get info on a task
   get_info()
   # assertions
```

Error:

```
    def _ensure_not_eager(self):
        if self.app.conf.task_always_eager:
            raise RuntimeError(
               "Cannot retrieve result with task_always_eager enabled")
E          RuntimeError: Cannot retrieve result with task_always_eager enabled

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py:334: RuntimeError
```

TLDR: What am I doing wrong in this test case to set task_always_eager to false because it is not changing it when the test runs?

Answer (score 11):

Celery's config object is dynamically updatable, so you can update it with:

`celery.conf.task_always_eager = False`

or `celery.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False` , if you're using pre-`4.0` Celery

You can do this on the fly, on a per-test basis, or during the "setUp" operation.